# DXL script for Doors 9.2

Tags: ibm-doors, ibm-rational

I am newbie to DXL scripting,
I am using DOORS 9.2,
Here i want to export only "**object Headings**" and "**object text**" of the current open module to **excel**.
I don't have any idea how to start can anyone help me with an example.
Your help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

Is using dxl a strict requirement or is the real requirement to export the Heading and Text attributes to excel?  Because you can do that without using DXL.

You need to create/modify a view (temporary or persistant) in the current open module with exactly the attributes you want.  Object Heading and Object Text in this case.  Remove from the view any other attributes, which are all the default attributes, and then add the new attributes.  The best way for you to do this is probably using the Edit->Columns... menu item which opens an Edit Columns Dialog.

Once you have the view, then it is a simple matter of going File->Export->Microsoft Office->Excel...

I am using 9.3.0.3, but from what I remember 9.2 really is not that much different.

Answer (score 3):

If you need this to be a script because you plan to do it often then the following code will output a csv file (which by default should open with Excel) with the heading and text of each object in the document.

```
Object o
Module m = current
Stream outfile = write("SomeFilePathHere.csv")

for o in m do
{
  outfile << o."Object Heading ", " o."Object Text" "\n"
}

close outfile
```

Otherwise James's response is accurate for avoiding scripting.

Comment: If you need to export text or strings, check out the function escape() in the DXL Reference Manual, too.

Comment: Be careful with DXL's escape function, it returns a string and if you use it on a large data set your string table size will explode. There's a Buffer version here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=373788&tstart=0